# Pausing one animation while keeping another — BAFluidView Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation

Okay...this is a long shot. Here's goes...

---

Background:

For a long time, I've been trying to figure out how to animate a wave horizontally across the screen while a long press is active. When the long press is interrupted or ends, the wave pauses in place, while continuing to ripple.

I've struggled to find a way to implement this. And then I recently stumbled across [BAFluidView](https://antiguab.github.io/bafluidview/). I was able to get the wave looking as I'd like it to:

[image]

---

The wave animates nicely. I can control when it starts. But, I can't pause it's motion across the screen while allowing the actual wave to continue.

About me:

1. I'm new to this.
2. I don't know much (almost none) Objective-C
3. The library was written in Objective-C

My ask:

Does anyone see a way for me to pause this damn wave?

If not here, what am I missing that could make this so much easier?

---

[Here's a link to the repo containing BAFluidView's code](https://antiguab.github.io/bafluidview/).

[And here's a link to the wave shown below](https://github.com/christopherdavis1/WaveDemo). It's not the app I'm working on, but it's an attempt to figure out how to pause this wave.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think pause animation is not possible but you remove current on going animation with below method.

```
[myView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks @Hitesh. I'm gonna keep experimenting. I'd love to figure out how to keep the cresting motion at the top of the wave while pausing the "fill" animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try WaveAnimationView instead. It is written in Swift and you can set the progress to any value between 0.0-1.0.

In case of animating the process of increasing or decreasing the progress of an instance of WaveAnimationView, I use a repeat timer, which looks like

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { Timer in
        if wave.progress == *yourvalue*{
            Timer.invalidate()
            return}
        wave.progress += 0.01
    }
```

Or you can try UIView.animate() method, which I didn't experiment though.